# Javascript prototype - applies not only for instance objects?

Tags: javascript

Prototypes are used throughout JavaScript as a convenient means of defining
properties and functionality that will be automatically applied to **instances of
objects**.

So if I write this :

```
function Ninja(){} 
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function(){ 
return true;
};

var ninja1 = Ninja();
```

Then ,  All ninjas will have the method.

But if it's only for instance objects - why does the following code works ?

```
Object.prototype.test1=function (){alert(this);};
Object.test1();
```

Object is a plain object and not an instance object.

Questions:

- it seems that the prototype also apply method for non-instance objects...

I couldn't find in mdn any explanation for *that exact behavior* .

Comment: I'll try and expand this into an answer when I have time if nobody else does so, but you have two different properties. Functions have a `prototype` property, which is used when they are called with `new`; all objects have an internal `[[Prototype]]` property which is what is used to find properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this doesn't work. Your code works, because you add function to `Object` prototype, and `Object` is function, that is instance of `Function`, and 'Function.prototype' is instance of `Object`

Comment: If try this with some other constructor except `Object` and `Function`

Comment: If so -  can you please tell me - why in this [code](http://jsbin.com/OrAGOrU/2/edit) I dont see the alert while in [this](http://jsbin.com/ULACixI/2/edit) one - i do see the alert ? if I create an instance by newing a function - it should go to the Function.prototype....no ?

Answer (score 1):

When you extend the prototype of `Object`, the property you add is available for all objects, as it's the root of all JS objects :

```
Object.prototype.test1 = function(){ console.log('test1') };
({}).test1(); // logs test1
(new Image()).test1(); // logs test1
```

And `Object`, like all constructors, is a function. And a function in JavaScript, is an object.